# Event in own package is not stored in db

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have an event that should be handled by a worker, within the namespace `App\Events` and inside the `app/events` folder. This way it works as expected.

Now I want to place it inside my own package with a new namespace `my/package`. The event is fired (I get an output inside the event constructor), but the event is not pushed inside the database.

Do events need to have the namespace `App\Events` to be handled correctly?

**Solution:**

I forgot to update the namespaces in the `EventServiceProvider`...

Comment: Events can have any namespace, but the calling and listener should use the same namespaced event. Also why would the event be pushed inside the database? No events get pushed to database. Is this something custom to your event handler or are you talking abt jobs?

Comment: My listener is queueable, so the values from the event will be pushed to the database

Comment: found my problem: i changed the namespaces but forgot to change it inside the EventServiceProvider